# Question about code for Arduino Beginner Project

Tags: c++, arduino

[Picture of the circuit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmMPf.png)

I'm trying to write a sketch with comments to control the 3 LEDs and button following these instructions:

- The sketch should start with a red light on.
- When the button is pressed, and as long as it’s kept pressed, the green light turns on.
- When the button is released, green light turns off,
  and the yellow light turns on for one second and then turns off.
- Followed by the red light turning on until the next time the button is pressed.

Right now I have the code working; however, it starts on yellow and then switches to red every time I run the code. I don't know how to make it start on red by default, and only after it is released, it starts going from yellow to red.

This is the code so far:

```
// Pin variables
int red = 9;        // Red LED connected to pin 9
int yellow = 10;    // Yellow LED connected to pin 10
int green = 11;     // Green LED connected to pin 11
int button = 2;     // Button connected to pin 2

// Variables for button state tracking
int buttonState = 0;                   // Current state of the button (LOW or HIGH)
int previousButtonState = HIGH;        // Variable to store the previous state of the button

void setup() {
  // Set pin modes for LEDs (OUTPUT) and button (INPUT)
  pinMode(red, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(yellow, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(green, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(button, INPUT);
}

void loop() {
  // Read the current state of the button
  buttonState = digitalRead(button);

  // Check if the button is pressed for the first time
  if (buttonState == HIGH && previousButtonState == LOW) {
    // Turn off red light, turn on green light
    digitalWrite(red, LOW);
    digitalWrite(green, HIGH);
  } 
  // Check if the button is continuously pressed
  else if (buttonState == HIGH && previousButtonState == HIGH) {
    // Keep the green light (do nothing)
  } 
  // Check if the button is released after being pressed
  else if (buttonState == LOW && previousButtonState == HIGH) {
    // Turn off green light, turn on yellow light, delay, turn off yellow light, turn on red light
    digitalWrite(green, LOW);
    digitalWrite(yellow, HIGH);
    delay(1000);  // Delay for 1000 milliseconds (1 second)
    digitalWrite(yellow, LOW);
    digitalWrite(red, HIGH);
  }

  // Save the current button state for the next time through
  previousButtonState = buttonState;
}
```

Comment: Think about the values of buttonState and previousButtonState the first time your code goes through loop.  How could you set previousButtonState to start with so this doesn't happen?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's something like this

```
int previousButtonState = LOW; //<= start with LOW

void setup(){
   ..... //initiate the pins as you do
   
   digitalWrite(red, HIGH); //turn the red ON on program start

}
```

You turn the red led ON in the setup and as you don't have a LOW/LOW situation in the IF statement the red will stay on until you've pressed the button for the first time